# A way to let non-Salesforce user to have a limited read/write access to internal data

Tags: security, user, community, portal, job

I have a following use case:

Company Alpha wants to use Salesforce for recruiting purpose. In order to do so, Alpha
would like to let non-Salesforce user to have a limited read/write access to internal objects (Contact, Job Application).

Non-Salesforce users should able to
- create/read/update/delete their contact information
- create/read/update/delete their Job Application using Contact object as a lookup

What are different methods I can use to achieve this? 
If external contact needs an account, should I leverage customer portal or community?
Is there a limit to number of portal user I can create in standard unlimited edition? What would be the cost per portal user?

Any input would be sincerely appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If the non-salesforce user does not need an account, then they can create a site and expose a VF page through it. (Setup > Develop > Sites)

In terms of Customer Portal or Communities, both would work. If you don't already have a Portal, then you will have to go with Communities since Portals are no longer supported.

You can read about licenses here: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US

Good luck!!

Luis Luciani

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a customer community for this.

You can technically do this with a Force.com site, but the security part would be tricky without exposing all data to the world.

Customer Community is the preferred approach, using just in time user provisioning.

Answer (score 0):

We have implement this with salesforce sites! Please follow steps below:

- You can go to Salesforce Setup Menu -> Develop -> Sites, and create a new Site.
- Create a visualforce page which is used to collect your contact/account information.
- In new site setting, add visualforce page into setting list.
- Access this page by https://your-site-domain/viusalforce-page-name

[image]

[image]